# WKWebView suppressesIncrementalRendering

Tags: uiwebview, load, wkwebview

I have set suppressesIncrementalRendering = NO; but WKWebView rendering slower than UIWebView.  At UIWebView, it appear the title first, than load images fully to appear images,at last , the title and images appear together. In WKWebView, the content of web  appear  after the title and images load finished . HOW to get the 
same with WKWebViEW as UIWebView's loading?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Any update?

Comment: Can you please help me with my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62482781/what-is-suppressesincrementalrendering-doing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been moved to the configuration of WKWebView:

```
myConfiguration.suppressesIncrementalRendering = YES;
```

Comment: This solves the problem? Because it seems like the exact opposite of what should be necessary.

Comment: Can you please help me with my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62482781/what-is-suppressesincrementalrendering-doing?